# sphinx как добавить текстовый атрибут

Tags: sphinxsearch

я добавляю запрос, указываю поля и сфинкс это идексирует и я могу спокойно искать по этим данным, НО при выводе он не указывает текстовые поля.

```
 sql_query = \
                SELECT product_id id, \
                model, m, description, body, \  # вот тут текстовые данные для поиска
                c_price price, url, enabled \
                FROM products WHERE 1=1 AND category_id>2
        # тут я указываю поля атрибуты, они как раз выводятся в массиве матчез
        sql_attr_float = price
        sql_attr_string = url
        # хз как добавить чтобы также был атрибут и индекс
        # sql_attr_string = model
        sql_attr_uint = enabled
```

Если же я эти поля (пример model) укажу как текстовые атрибуты, все они уже не участвуют в поиске... я сразу получаю меньше результатов...

я просто хочу чтобы поле было и атрибутом, чтоб я мог его видеть в результате запроса, а также и поиск по нему был.

вот если я делаю select * то получаю только атрибуты

```
mysql> select *, WEIGHT() from simpla where match('процессор core Ivy') ;
+--------+--------------+--------+---------+----------+
| id     | price        | url    | enabled | weight() |
+--------+--------------+--------+---------+----------+
|  50077 | 16190.000000 | 50077  |       0 |     4643 |
|  50942 | 17950.000000 | 50942  |       0 |     4643 |
|  46951 | 21350.000000 | 46951  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46952 |  7950.000000 | 46952  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46957 | 22240.000000 | 46957  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46959 | 24500.000000 | 46959  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46961 | 16070.000000 | 46961  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46962 | 27890.000000 | 46962  |       0 |     3638 |
|  46963 | 30490.000000 | 46963  |       0 |     3638 |
|  47064 | 32110.000000 | 47064  |       0 |     3638 |
|  48107 | 26750.000000 | 48107  |       0 |     3638 |
|  52358 | 14700.000000 | 52358  |       0 |     3638 |
|  53770 | 19230.000000 | 53770  |       0 |     3625 |
|  53772 | 26770.000000 | 53772  |       0 |     3625 |
|  51432 | 16460.000000 | 51432  |       0 |     2638 |
| 114200 | 13230.000000 | 114200 |       0 |     1601 |
+--------+--------------+--------+---------+----------+
```

так сказать для себе, не удобно ориентироваться что нашлось, не вижу, вижу только цифры и веса :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ подсказали на форуме сфинкса
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-string

надо так

```
sql_field_string = model
```